# Android project hangs on deploy

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I'm attempting a very novice Xamarin Forms app and it builds in an instant, but then seems to hang when deploying to the emulator, i.e. I aborted after well over 20 minutes. In the output window, under `Xamarin Diagnostics`, I get the following last few entries:

```
[I:]:                     Found Android SDK. API levels: 22, 26
[I:]:                     Tracking android devices started
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: emulator-5554    device
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 1 devices
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
[D:]:                     Tracking avd started
[D:]:                     avd watcher *.ini path: 'C:\Users\brady\.android\avd'
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
[D:]:                     avd watcher: got device list from avd with 1 devices
```

This is my debugging target:

[image]

My Xamarin Forms projects were working about a month ago, but since then I experimented with nearly every other Android enabled IDE and maybe that somehow affected my AVD.

What can I look at or change to correct this problem?

I have since learnt I must use the `Emulator Manager` to create an emulator. Now when I try and open the Emulator Manager, it says I must use the `SDK Manager` to downgrade the SDK tools to v25.x. When I open the `SDK Manager`, it says it must be updated, and presents an `Update` button. Pressing the button directs me to a download page with no download button:

[image]

The `Get Started` button takes me to the docs page for the SDK Manager. Now how am I supposed to update this problem child SDK Manager?

Comment: Make sure Emulator is installed in your Device. and if possible share screenshot of your page that you are trying to run. so that we can get more idea what issues you are facing

Comment: @Divya Do you mean the Emulator must be installed on the AVD? I don't need an emulator on the device itself. Then, what do you mean by "what page", the Activity? I don't understand what you mean by page, and why a screenshot, why not just add the code?

Comment: Yes i mean't by sharing Code only but if there is a screenshot with Visual Studio i can see the Configuration in menu like which device is selected, etc.
also if you are using AVD, try`Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator` for Android, it will solve your problem. AVD might take a long time for Loading Everytime while using Xamarin Forms. VS Emulator works very fine

Comment: @Divya The emulator wasn't installed - I re-installed VS and forgot about it. I have added a screenshot that I hope is what you wanted, but I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: What is your emulator architecture , `x86` or `arm` ?

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT I don't know. When I installed the emulator from this page, 'https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator', I didn't see any option for setting that. I don't know where to look in VS either.

Comment: You could use `Andriod virtual Device` to create a emulator, you could find it in Tools -> Android -> `Android Emulator Manager`.

Comment: Then you could create a `x86` architecture emulator, enable the [Hardware Acceleration](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/1-hardware-acceleration/), Android SDK Emulator is prohibitively slow without hardware acceleration.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT Please see my edits.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160587/discussion-between-york-shen-msft-and-profk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-installed VS2017, but the latest, v15.5.1, then recreated the project, and now everything is working fine. VS even starts the emulator automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If your project compiles but won't deploy, then Visual Studio is probably not connected to your emulator.

I would recommend using [Visual Studio Emulator for Android](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/) as it is much faster and has worked on every device I have used it on.

On some computers Visual Studio does not connect to the emulator when it starts. A workaround is to find the devices IP address and connect to it manually:

First open Visual Studio Emulator for Android and start one of the emulators
[image: Visual Studio Emulator for Android]

Next in the emulator select tools, a popup window will open, select the 'Network' tab and under the list of network adaptors note down the `preferred` IP address. Here my one is `169.254.160.177`. 
[image: Visual Studio Emulator Network Tab]

Then in Visual Studio open 'Android Adb Command Prommpt' and enter `adb connect 169.254.160.177`
[image: Android Adb Command Prompt]

Now that Visual Studio is connected to the emulator the application will be deployed to the device. You will need to connect to the emulator every time you restart it (don't close it while your programming).

**Note:** On some computers, Visual Studio will connect to the emulator automatically.